# Inventory Stock report Using 3 Sql Tabel Out Put in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I have 4 tables: Purchase, Purchase Return, Sale, Sale Return.

All tables include the same columns.

In **Purchase Table** transaction:

```
Id     Date          ItemCode    Qty    Purchase Rate

1      |01-01-17       00001    20       500
```

In **sale Table** table transaction:

```
Id     Date       ItemCode     Qty     sale Rate

1     01-01-17     00001       10      500
```

I want to display date-wise report in Crystal Report like this:

```
Opening Stock  ItemCode  Purchase  Purchase Return   Sale    SaleReturn   Balance  
 0              00001     20           0             10         0           10 

 10             00001     0            0             0          0            10
```

I tried this query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpStockQtyDate1]

as 
Begin

 with i as 
 (select SIZE, sum(qty) as QtyIn from PurchaseTable where date >='2017-02-14'     and date <='2017-02-14'   group by Size),
  o as 
  (
    select size, sum (qty) as QtyOut from InvoiceTable where  date >='2017-02-14' and date <='2017-02-14'  group by Size)
    select COALESCE (i.Size,o.Size) as size,COALESCE (QtyIn,0) as stock_in,
           COALESCE (QtyOut,0) as stock_Out,
           COALESCE (QtyIn,0)-COALESCE(QtyOut,0) as Stock_Balance
                from i 
                full join 
                     o
                on o.size=i.Size
End
```

Comment: Why do you have two row for ItemCode? Why is one Opening Stock Qty 0 and other Opening Stock Qty 10? If you want a date, I don't see a date column in the result set.

Comment: Item code is only one row this view is generated report view 
when i generate report from 1-1-17 to 2-1-17 there is opening stock is 0 + purchase 20 - purchase return 0 - sale 10 + sale return 0 = stock balance 10 
when i generate report from 2-1-17 to 3-1-17 then my opening stock will be 10 because 1-1-17 balance is 10 
and date is in my table

Comment: I figured as much but you don't explicitly include the dates in your sample output (third table). It also helps if you give us a sample data set to work with.

Comment: Id     Date          ItemCode    Qty    Purchase Rate

1      |01-01-17       00001    20       500

Comment: lock at top my tables with dates dear.

Comment: I think you want to use running total feature in crystal to do what you want. You don't need to write a procedure.

Comment: yes dear i want running total with this columns

Comment: search on google for: how to use running totals in crystal reports  -- I wouldn't consider this question a programming question at this point since the feature is built into the software